# How to set the first item in a list to a dictionary key, and the following items as the value for that key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is what I'm trying:

```
def dict1(filename):
        try:
            file_handle=open(filename,"r")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None
        newdict = {}
        for line in file_handle:
            list1 = line.split(",")
            (k, v) = list1
            newdict[k]] = v
        return newdict
```

The text file has lines like such:

```
cow 1,dog 1
john 1,rob 1,ford 1
robert 1,kyle 1,jake 1
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary like so:

```
{'cow 1': ['dog 1'],
 'john 1': ['rob 1','ford 1'],
 'robert 1': ['kyle 1, 'jake 1']}
```

The problem is in the (k,v), how can i set the k to the first item in the list, and the v to all items following it?

Comment: If *a* is your list and *d* is your dictionary, then simply assign *d[a[0]] = a[1:]*

Comment: thank you! could you quickly explain the a[1:]?

Comment: a[1:] refers to the tail of the list a - i.e. the list excluding the first item.

Comment: What’s wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

result = {}
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:           #Iterate each row
        result[row[0]] = row[1:] #column 0 as key and others as value. 

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'cow 1': ['dog 1'],
 'john 1': ['rob 1', 'ford 1'],
 'robert 1': ['kyle 1', 'jake 1']}
```